# React | this.props.function inside a function will not be called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm working on a Checklist with React and MaterialUI consisting out of two components, one that contains the data and another one that edits it, but there occurs the problem that the called function (handleDeleteChip()), which is passed   on with props, will not be executed.

Parent Component:

```
export default class CheckList extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        taskData: {}
    }

 this.handleDeleteChip = this.handleDeleteChip.bind(this)


 handleDeleteChip = (chipToDelete) => () => {
    let obj = this.state.taskData
    delete obj[chipToDelete]
    this.setState({taskData: obj})
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                <AddToDoComponent handleDeleteChip={this.handleDeleteChip}/>
            }
        </div>
```

Child Component:

```
class AddToDoComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        chipData: props.taskData,
        updateCondition: true
    }
    this.deleteHandler = this.deleteHandler.bind(this)
}
deleteHandler(chipToDelete){
    this.props.handleDeleteChip(chipToDelete)
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you use function deleteHandler in child ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not called? It looks to me like, assuming it is called, it won't cause a rerender, as you're directly mutating state.

Comment: @Arthur 

`const chip = (<div>
            {Object.keys(this.state.chipData).map((k, i) => (
                <p key={i}>
                    <Chip
                        style={{float: "left",  margin: 5}}
                        label={k}
                        onDelete={() => {this.deleteHandler({k})}}
                    />
                </p>
            ))}
        </div>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of *handleDeleteChip* should be:

```
handleDeleteChip(chipToDelete) {
    let obj = this.state.taskData
    delete obj[chipToDelete]
    this.setState({taskData: obj})
};
```

or if you are using a functional component

```
const handleDeleteChip = (chipToDelete) => {
    ....
};
```

Also, the brackets ({}) into the parent render are not needed.
Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind `this` from the prop value.

```
export default class CheckList extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        taskData: {}
    }

 //Remove: this.handleDeleteChip = this.handleDeleteChip.bind(this)


 handleDeleteChip = (chipToDelete) => () => {
    let obj = this.state.taskData
    delete obj[chipToDelete]
    this.setState({taskData: obj})
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                <AddToDoComponent handleDeleteChip={this.handleDeleteChip.bind(this)}/>
            }
        </div>
```